# Get base path in http.HandleFunc

Tags: go

Is it possible to get the base path from the `http.HandleFunc` in the `http.Request` or `http.ResponseWriter` as a variable (first argument in `http.HandleFunc`) ?

```
http.HandleFunc("/the-base-path/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    // get "/the-base-path/" here as a variable
    ...
})
```

Comment: `http.Request` has a `URL` field of type `*url.URL`, which has `Path` field. Would that not suit your needs?

Comment: @jub0bs I need the exact variable defined in the first argument

Comment: By default, that's not possible. Why don't you simply assign the pattern in question to a variable in scope with the second argument to `http.HandleFunc`?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer.

[The function that serves requests is](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.2:src/net/http/server.go;drc=867babe1b1587ab6961c1d6274be2426e90bf5d4;l=2474)

```
func (mux *ServeMux) ServeHTTP(w ResponseWriter, r *Request) {
    if r.RequestURI == "*" {
        if r.ProtoAtLeast(1, 1) {
            w.Header().Set("Connection", "close")
        }
        w.WriteHeader(StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    h, _ := mux.Handler(r)
    h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

The function [`mux.Handler`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.2:src/net/http/server.go;drc=867babe1b1587ab6961c1d6274be2426e90bf5d4;l=2419) that looks up the handler for the request returns both the handler and the corresponding patter (aka `"/the-base-path/"`)

But as you can see `mux.ServeHTTP` **drops** the pattern returned by `mux.Handler`. There is no direct way for the handler to identify the pattern that was matched against the request.